# How do I annotate a Map<String, Entity> when the map key does not come from the entity

Tags: hibernate, dictionary

I've read the entries in this forum discussing how to annotate a typed Map with Hibernate and I've read the Hibernate docs that are referenced here. None of them answer my question. My code is as follows:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="administrator_filters")
private Map<String, BaseFilter> filters;
```

I want to use an arbitrary String as the key to this map that contains a BaseFilter object (which is one of my entities) and store it in the join table. Hibernate seems to require a property from the BaseFilter object as the key in the map.

I see the following error
    Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'administrator_filters'.

I've added nullable=false to JoinColumn elements in the JoinTable and MapKey annotation, but I always get the same error.

I could add a property to the BaseFilter containing the map key, but I am trying not to do that. The Hibernate docs say:

```
Maps can borrow their keys from one of the associated entity properties or have dedicated columns to store an explicit key.
```

But they don't explain how to use an explicit key.

Answer (score 0):

```
@MapKey(columns = {@Column(name = "mapkeycolumn")} , targetElement = BaseFilter.class)
```

targetElement is optional when using generic collections